# @media: if samsung galaxy s4 is 1920x1080?

Tags: css, smartphone

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:1280px)" href="css/article1280.css">
```

I'm in the middle of coding my responsive CSS and I realized that the Samsung Galaxy S4 smartphone has a screen resolution of 1080x1920—my 23" monitor is 1920x1080. I've never browsed on this phone (I have an iPhone 3 with a resolution of 320x480 which is what I thought all smartphones were *around*, somewhere under 800 pixels wide) so I'm a bit perplexed. How am I supposed to create a mobile website for a smartphone with a screen resolution of 1080x1920?

Comment: Is your website unusable in its current form?

Comment: Very usable but I want to make all of the navigation bigger and easier to use and slim everything down to single columns if it's going to be in a handheld device.

Comment: Are you using the viewport meta tag? Media queries won't have any effect without it.

Comment: I wanted to ask about the viewport meta tag also. I read a website that says while the iPhone 5's resolution width is 980px it is effectively 320px. Is that why the viewport meta tag works?

Comment: What's so special about the Galaxy that it should have specific styles, while another device with similar resolution should not?  If the answer is *touch*, then you're barking up the wrong tree with media queries.

Answer (score 20):

Galaxy S4 reports 360px x 640px to the browser

Aspect ratio is 9/16

Pixel ratio is 3

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 360px)

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 9/16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some media queries that you might find useful in this case are:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait | landscape) { ... }

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: #/#) { ... }
```

Here's a link with more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

use `@media screen and (max-device-width: your dimension here)`.

Comment: Why use device width? If someone is viewing on a smaller browser window it'd make sense to make it display in the best way possible

Answer (score 0):

When designing on a GS4 it renders as a regular widescreen unless you use the viewport tag in your headers. I posted the example I use to make it responsive @ [Samsung Galaxy S4 Responsive Design @media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501270/samsung-galaxy-s4-responsive-design-media)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the viewport meta tag in your head section. Something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This tells the user-agent to take into account the pixel density and rescale accordingly. So your 1080px width Samsung Galaxy S4 will act like a 360px width screen.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working!

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0) and (max-width: 1080px), screen and (max-width: 480px)
```