# Can I combine these media queries to be an Or statement?

Tags: android, css, media-queries, galaxy

This is a link to the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923561/media-if-samsung-galaxy-s4-is-1920x1080)

Here writes the code like this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 360px)

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 9/16)
```

How would I use that all at once? I am assuming it is with comma's but I am unsure and wouldn't know if it were working anyhow?

For Example would it be like this?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 360px), @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3), @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 9/16) {The edits go here}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome on SO! Does [this question (and answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994664/combining-css-media-queries) relate(s) to what you want to achieve? What I'm sure is there will only have one `@media` at the beginning and a set of rules `{ .selector { declaration1} .selector2 { declarations234} }` at the end. Not 2 or more `@media` separated by commas and/or `and`.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if those webkit and device aspect ratio's are the same thing as width... just saying it in a different way.

Comment: oh yea... it should start at screen correct?